# why does it matter to sync nodes with time?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, geth-debugging

As we know, `time` gets set on a block's header as the miner's current local time. Each node while accepting a block, checks if the new block's time is more than `parent` 's time and is not also in the future too far.

Question 1. Why doesn't `geth` just put the UTC time directly on the `header ?`  why does the local time set on the computer matter ? I also don't understand how `NTP` matter in this case since all it does is check's some difference and logs the warning message and that's all

Comment: it does put time DIRECTLY in the header. thats the `Time` field

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not sure if this answers your question, but: Geth uses Unix time which is universal (i.e. not dependant on timezone).

Comment: yes, that's why I am curious why need for `NTP` protocol at all

Comment: Oh, node operator local clocks might not be synced which means your peers might drop your blocks:

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/123e934e72dbbc63281858ec20c29beb6f70d9ba/core/blockchain.go#L1648

> "I also don't understand how NTP matter in this case since all it does is check's some difference and logs the warning message and that's all."

You need to sync your clock yourself, since it's a privileged call.

Comment: so we can't get correct UTC value if the local time is wrong, correct ?

Comment: Yea, I think that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem are block with a timestamp in the future. Should a client accept them? If the timestamp is within certain range seems reasonable to accept them.

If it is too far into the future perhaps it is some kind of selfish mining attack.

Comment: Yes, but I think my question was a little bit different. I understand consensus, but I am asking how a good miner puts a timestamp on a block when it creates that.  I am not sure why `NTP` is necessary. when the miner has to put a timestamp, it can pull the `NTP` server and whatever it returns, put on a block. But it doesn't work like that. When you join network as a miner, it makes you sync with NTP first so that your local time is correct. I guess, this is because it doesn't do NTP request every time a block starts to get mined. I don't know . :(

Comment: @NikaKurashvili I don't know why NTP is required. I'd guess that someone had lost a lot because the time was wrong and they complained enough for the developers to require it.

Comment: If the local time is wrong in terms of the returned value from NTP, the `geth` does the `log.warn`. Do you think this prevents connecting to the network or still allows it ? I don't know how powerful is `log.warn` and if it halts the program.

Comment: Because I know that if local time is wrong, it somehow makes sure you get disconnected from more and more peers, resulting in you are kicked out of the network

Comment: I'd guess that over time clients will have different views of the latest blocks and they will disconnect other nodes that do not match the queries thay are expecting.

Comment: Yeah, that could be other explanation. I guess, `warning` is just warning for the miner.